# ClrMd Execute "~*k" returns stack traces with clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal instead of correct values

Tags: windbg, clrmd

When I execute "~*k" command via ClrMd, it returns stack traces with clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal instead of correct values. It looks like symbols are not loaded.
If I perform "~*k" command directly in WinDBG, everything looks well.

```
  this.DataTarget = DataTarget.LoadCrashDump(pathToMemoryDump, CrashDumpReader.DbgEng);
  this.DataTarget.SymbolLocator.SymbolCache = @"C:\symbols";
  this.DataTarget.EnumerateModules().ToList().ForEach((m) =>
            {
                this.DataTarget.SymbolLocator.FindBinary(m);
                this.DataTarget.SymbolLocator.FindPdb(m);


            });
  this.ClrRuntime = DataTarget.ClrVersions[0].CreateRuntime();
```

Then, I'm using Execute method to perform the query against loaded memory dump:

```
(IDebugControl)client.Execute(DEBUG_OUTCTL.ALL_CLIENTS, cmd, DEBUG_EXECUTE.DEFAULT);
```

Do anyone have any suggestion?
My intention to get correct stack traces for native threads.

Comment: And you use `c:\symbols` in WinDbg only? Why not download symbols from Microsoft?

Comment: C:\symbols is symbol cache. The pdp file is downloaded into C:\symbols folder well.

Comment: `clr!DllUnregisterServerInternal` looks like a native frame to me... although symbols do not appear to be resolved.

Comment: Was able to resolve it with loading symbols via debugSymbolsClient debugSymbolsClient.SetSymbolPath(SymbolCachePath);

Answer (score 0):

Set your symbol path

```
var symbols = DataTarget.DebuggerInterface as IDebugSymbols;
symbols.SetSymbolPath("http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols");
```